# Declaring size of 3D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I needed to have a 2D array of vectors of myClass objects, so that I can access one of those vectors using coordinates within the array (like a 2D plane). But the size must be determined at runtime. Because of this, I decided to make it a 3D vector declared as such

```
   vector<vector<vector <myClass> > > vex;
```

That way, I can just declare the size during runtime. However, I can't figure out the syntax for declaring the size of the first two outer vectors. With a single vector, it's declared like this:

```
vex(size);
```

But how is this done for a multi-vector like mine? Such that I can access one of the myClass vectors using

```
vex[x][y];
```

Comment: Note there are not "two outer vectors". There is an outer vector, which contains a bunch of vectors (not just one vector), which contain more vectors.

Comment: If this question is for exploring the knowledge base of C++, then that is fine. But if this is for PROD usage, then you have to reconsider your class design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the vector to be filled with default constructed `myClass` instances you can do this:

```
vector<vector<vector <myClass> > > vex(size, vector<vector<myClass>>(size, vector<myClass>(size)));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that without filling it myClass instances? So that the myClass vector is initially empty?

Comment: @Bob map of map of maps, I suppose.

Comment: @Bob not if you want to always access them with vex[x][y].

Comment: Well I know you wouldn't be able to access them initially. I mean so that I can push stuff in later with vex[x][y].push_back(....)

Comment: @Bob omit the last `size`. Not sure why you would want that, but that would give you a vector of vectors of empty vectors.

Comment: One last thing. The code you gave is how you would set the size when you declare it. But I need to declare it initially in the .h file, then set the size at runtime in my .cpp file. Is there a syntax for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typedef` to simplify things:

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<MyClass> MyClassV;
typedef std::vector<MyClassV> MyClass2V;
typedef std::vector<MyClass2V> MyClass3V;
```

//...

Then initialize like this:

```
MyClass3V vect(num1, MyClass2V(num2, MyClassV(num3)));
```

This creates a `num1 x num2 x num3` vector of `MyClass`.

If you want a completely empty vector, then just

```
MyClass3V vect;
```

does this.  Then later you can `resize()` each dimension to whatever you need:

```
vect.resize(4, MyVect2V(2)); // creates a 4 x 2 x 0 vector.
```